# Go next page with submit button

Tags: php, pagination, laravel-8, laravel-pagination

*I'm using laravel 8.

I need to use submit button to redirect to next page. I've tried several methods but nothing works. (another function, href=nextPageUrl, scripts...) I have no idea how to resolve.

```
<form autocomplete="off" role="form" id="update-address" method="POST"
                action="{{ route('postageaddress.update') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="formOrders">
                @csrf
                <div class="card-body p-0">
______________
table
_____________________
<div class="card-footer row mt-3">
                    <div class="pagination pagination-md float-left">
                        {{ $orders->withQueryString()->links() }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="ml-auto">
                        <div class="btn-group mr-2">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"  onclick="window.location.reload();confirm('Deseja cancelar as alterações da página?')">Cancel</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="btn-group mr-2">   
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="submit">Save and continue</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Your submit should be handled by a Controller, which should then be responsible for redirecting to the correct page. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76393319/edit) and include the Controller method that handles this submit action.